# Angular: Try to change the font color with ngx color picker

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I want to change the font color from an array entry, which i put in a textfield.
I tried it with ngx color picker and i was able to change the background color. But currently i want do the same with the font color but unfortunately without success.

My html code:

```
      <!--color picker-->

    <span class="form-group">
      <label>Background: </label>
      <input class="form-control" [value]="color" [style.background]="color" [cpOutputFormat]="'rgba'" [cpCancelButton]="true"  (colorPickerClose)="updateColor(color)"
      [(colorPicker)]="color" style="position: absolute;"/>
    </span>
    
 <div class="smoothie">
   <div class="scroller"  class="textarea" *ngFor="let file of getFileAnalyze" [style.color]="colors[file.fileCategory]" [style.background]="color" >
     
    <span [innerHTML]="file.date"></span> <span [innerHTML]="file.content | highlight: searchedTerm" ></span> </div>
    </div>
```

my typescript code: (i was not able to chnage the color for the first array entry and make it flexibility for the user)

```
  //------color picker------
  title = 'colorPicker';
  color: string = '#ffffff';
  arrayColors: any = {
    color1: '#2883e9',
    color2: '#e920e9',
    color3: 'rgb(255,245,0)',
    color4: 'rgb(236,64,64)',
    color5: 'rgba(45,208,45,1)'
  };
  selectedColor: string = 'color1';
//---------
colors: {[category:string]: any} = {kts250:this.color, kts250expansion:"09050ef8", vci_esitronic:"#006633", vci_cdevices:"#9840bb", updatemanager:"#479bfc",vci_messages:"#CC0066"}
```

i mean why it doesn't change the color for the kts250 entry ? Can anyone help me please ? :(

Comment: You are not using color picker correctly. Read the documentation of ngx-color-picker

Comment: i already read it but i didn't understand what i did wrong :/ Can you explain it please